# Operator ++ in an IF statement in C

Tags: c

I have this:

```
...
int charry = 0;
if (l[charry++] == 'a'){
    whatever;
}
...
```

The question is: will charry be increased anyway or just if `l[charry] == 'a'` evaluates to true?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Definitely compile-error. At least it was...

Comment: Try it and you'll know. It will take less time than posting it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>`char` is a reserved key word. Program would not even compile.</strike>

---

**EDIT:**  Before comparison, both operand of `==` will be evaluated and hence any side effect to expressions will take place. Therefore `charry` will be modified.

Comment: My god..I just put that without thinking about it... Edited.

Comment: To be pedantic: The side effect will *not* necessarily have taken place before the comparison. At that point it's certain to happen, but it may be delayed until the next [sequence point](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/395760) (which would be after the comparison). So if you did something more complicated like `if (l[charry++] == 'a' && charry == 1)` you'd have undefined behavior.

Comment: @delnan; I never said that side effect will take place "before/after". :)

Comment: So what? Still worth knowing :-)

Answer (score 3):

It will absolutely be incremented by 1 after the if-statement. <strike>if you choose to name your variable something other than a reserved keyword.</strike>

```
int charry = 0;
if (l[charry++] == 'a'){
    whatever;
}
// charry is now 1
```

If `charry` is used again before the next sequence point, as user delnan explained in his comment, you would have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, you guys are so critical (and I appreciate it). It was a mistake, I am not using "char" as a name, haha.

Comment: "It will be incremented ... after the if-statement" is a bit imprecise: It will be incremented sometime between reading the old value of `charry` and the branch decision of the `if()`. At least as far as the language is concerned. The optimizer, of course, may move the increment pretty much anywhere else as long as the code behaves as if the increment happened within the parentheses of the `if()`.